# A word to describe a person who can’t voice their ideas

Tags: word-request

I need a word to describe a person who is reluctant to express what they’re thinking. For example, I suggest a plan and ask for that person’s opinion. He or she will say it’s ok, although they’re not really satisfied with it, maybe because they don’t want to object to my idea or they don’t have a better idea. But then when we carry out the plan, they will express their opinion at the point when they can’t stand the plan anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this fits the bills:

> **[Reticent](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reticent)** 
> 1 : inclined to be silent or uncommunicative in speech.

I would also describe this kind of person as [reserved](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reserved)

Comment: Normally that person is talkative. It’s just when being asked for opinions that she can’t be clear about it.

Comment: Maybe "non-assertive".

Comment: @user117023 In the context of the conversation itself, where they ***aren't*** being talkative, they are being *reticent*.

Comment: If I get it right, reticent is more like a state when people don’t want to share something rather than a characteristic. In my case, it’s not because she doesn’t want to share her feelings or thoughts, it’s because she doesn’t know what is good for her or she doesn’t want to hurt others’ feelings. For example, I want to buy her a shirt and ask her whether she likes it and in case she doesn’t, I will take it back and buy her another one. She will say she likes it with reluctance and she will never put it on.

Answer (score 0):

The word **compliant** comes to mind:

> *disposed to agree with others or obey rules, especially to an excessive degree; acquiescent.*

That definition also provides the word **acquiescent**.

> **Acquiescence**: *the reluctant acceptance of something without protest.*

**Acquiescent** may be good here as its definition includes the term you used, **reluctant**, though I feel **compliant** would perhaps be a bit more common in general conversation, despite being perhaps a little less accurate in your given scenario.